# How to iterate and extract values from a list of objects

Tags: scala, spray-json

I am new to Scala and Spray. I have an input JSON that basically maps to these case classes. I have managed to get the json parsed and this the output I am seeing:

```
case class First(param1:Boolean,param2:List[Parameter])
case class Parameter(name:String,age:Int)

val jsonCollection = input.convertTo[First]
val first=jsonCollection.map(x=>println(x.sql))
```

returns me this value

```
Vector(List(First(true,"ram",32),First(true,"siv",22)))
```

I am not sure how to iterate and retrieve values for each of the list object.

Comment: are you saying you want to retrieve values of `Vector[List[First]]`? you can `first.foreach { firsts => firsts.foreach {elem => println(elem.parama1)}}`

Comment: Are you sure it returns this value? Because your `First` has only two arguments.

Comment: Consider posting a code which runs here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org (you can add the `spray-json` library to the build)

Comment: @prayagupd - That worked thanks a lot.  You are right this is not the actual code I just wanted the logic. The return is only 2 values.

Comment: @Siva awesome, go ahead and answer your own question. its fun :)